# Facebook fetches wrong thumbnails on some posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We have a new site with some images and we share the new posts on out Facebook page with a scheduler app. Everything is okay except, that on some posts the thumbnail isn't correct, for example this post went out with a wrong thumbnail: [Quidditch Practice](http://www.moodfactory.net/cuteness/785-quidditch-practice/)

You can see this on the Facebook page: [Our FB page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/When-you-just-say-k-or-lol-I-close-the-convo/462924665001)

If you check out the source code, you can see, that the og:image tag is always filled out, with the RIGHT image URL. I already modified the code, that this og:image tag grabes the smaller 150x150 version of the image. I was hoping Facebook fails on grabbing the bigger images randomly, but this wasn't the solution, still getting wrong thumbnails.

I'm now out of ideas, because the Facebook debugger tool always shows this posts with the right thumbnails, so i really don't know whats wrong...

The scheduler app fetches this posts also with the right thumbnails!

Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The server is caching your previous image, representing it as if it is real-time. Give it some time to propagate amongst the servers.

Comment: I don't really get this :) We have other sites like this (with this frontend code) and there are no problems. We create here the posts and after 4-7 hours the scheduler posts them on the Facebook page.